# If some sequence $(x_{n})$ is convergent in $X$ show that $(x_{n})$ is stationary (eventually constant).

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be non-empty set and 
$ T = \{ V \subseteq X : card ( X \backslash V) \leq \aleph_{0} \} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ topology on $X$. If some sequence $(x_{n})$ is convergent in $X$ show that $(x_{n})$ is stationary ( sequence that eventually becomes constant sequence //after some $n \in \mathbb{N} $ all members of sequence are equal).

I tried to prove it by contradiction but I got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by $card(X\setminus V)\leq \aleph_0$ ? Also explain what a "stationary sequence mean"

Comment: @user657324 forgot to write down that $T$  is topology, sorry

Comment: as what I know, **stationary** is when the sequence becomes constant after some $N >> 0$.

Comment: @freehumorist: It's anyway good to precise this point when you ask the question. By the way, I don't really understand all these upvotes... No real definition, no real try from the OP...

Comment: @user560461 Can you explain where you got stuck? Write down your attempted proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x_n\rightarrow x$ but there are $x_n\neq x$ with $n$ arbitrarily large.  Consider the neighborhood of $x$ defined by $V:=X - \{x_n | x_n\neq x\}$.  Does the sequence $(x_n)$ eventually lie in this neighborhood?